# Window object not defined in jasmine

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, window

I am trying to test a method where one of the thing that it does it lock orientation of screen. Jasmine however is throwing error in the line:
`(<any>window).screen.orientation.lock('portrait')` saying that `undefined is not a constructer`.

I even tried not using typescript types and just `window.screen.msOrientationLock('landscape')`  and other window.screen methods but I get same error. I have the `_$window_` injected in `beforeEach` of my tests too.

Testing if it locks is not necessary part of my test so is there some way to skip this specific line or correct this error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was easy. I had to inject window object and assign it to a global variable in my global `beforeEach` like this:

`$window = _$window_`;

Then, the next issue was that the property `orientation` was not available in the `window.screen` object unfortunately. I just had to mock it inside my spec like this:

`$window.screen.orientation = {
  lock: function() { return; }
};`

Just had to do this before spying/calling the method which had `window.screen.orientation.lock` method inside it.